# Can a some() function replace nested forEach()?

Tags: javascript, function, foreach

I need to replace two (nested) forEach loops with a some function. The purpose of the code block is to check if the [1] elements in arrayOne are within the max & min of arrayTwo.

The code currently works fine and looks like this:

```
    var result = false;
    arrayOne.forEach((arrayOneElement) => {
      arrayTwo.forEach((arrayTwoElement) => {
        if (arrayOneElement[1] > arrayTwoElement[1].max || arrayOneElement[1] < arrayTwoElement[1].min) {
          result = true;
        }
      });
    });
```

Let me know if it isn't clear enough. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you mean a `some(...)` function or `sum(...)` function?

Comment: Yes, a some() function

Comment: result is true if an element value is NOT between min and max, as written.  Confusing.

Comment: well you will need two some() not one

Comment: Do you want to check that *every* element in arrayOne is between *some* element in arrayTwo's "min" and "max" property?  Do you want to filter arrayOne to find the elements that conform?  What is your desired output?

Comment: Java != Javascript - Java does not have a `some()` function.  Java tag removed.

Comment: do you have some data and wanted result?

Comment: The answer is, "yes, you can do that with `some()`." Rewriting your code to spec isn't really on-topic here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `Array#some` in this situation. It would be done like this

```js
const result = arrayOne.some((arrayOneElement) => {
  return arrayTwo.some((arrayTwoElement) => {
    return arrayOneElement[1] > arrayTwoElement[1].max || arrayOneElement[1] < arrayTwoElement[1].min
  });
});
```

Comment: @displayName Always happy to help. Good luck on the rest of your project

Answer (score -1):

You could replace `forEach` with `some` and get destructured values from items.

```
const 
    result = arrayOne.some(([, value]) =>
        arrayTwo.some(([, { min, max }]) => value > max || value < min)
    );
```